# Asset Studio (Android Studio) fails to read svg files

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to import images into my Android Studio project. `right click on a folder in the project-> New -> Image Asset` launches an Asset Studio window. If I navigate to a png file, I see previews for the different sizes it will generate. However, if I navigate to an SVG file, the previews are blank, and the tool generates empty (transparent) pngs.

[image]
[image]

If I use [the online version](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=ffffff%2C100) of asset studio in Google Chrome, svgs work fine! I have many images to work with, however, and importing each of those files individually seems painful.

Has anyone found a workaround to make the Android Studio (v0.8.9) version of Asset Studio handle SVGs?

Comment: Someone in google hates svg: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9710 is from 2010 (Even the browser didn't support SVG until Android 3.0) :) Also version 1.0RC2 still does the same and I guess you'll have to png convert your files (there are batch processing tools for that) first.